# Field correctly validated, but no error shown on view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I have a problem with showing the error on view (html page).

The form looks like this (only one field shown for clariness):

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{addinvoice}" th:object="${invoicedata}" method="post">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li>
            <label>Data odbioru<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="date" th:field="*{receptionDate}" id="receptionDate">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('receptionDate')}" th:errors="*{receptionDate}">Error.</span>
        </li>
```

Then I have a custom javax `Validator`:

```
@Component
public class InvoiceFormValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return InvoiceData.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "receptionDate", "Reception date is empty!");
        InvoiceData invoicedata = (InvoiceData) target;
        if (invoicedata.getReceptionDate() == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("receptionDate", "Reception date cannot be empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

The validation is doubled because I wanted to be 100% sure that it is validating correctly.

Now for the `Controller` part, it looks like this (the rest of the code is removed for clariness)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addinvoice", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String addInvoice(@CurrentUser Contractor contractor, @ModelAttribute @Validated InvoiceData invoicedata, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.error("BINDING RESULT ERROR: " + result.getAllErrors().toString());
            logger.error("ERROR: " + result.getFieldError("receptionDate").getCode());
            attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.invoicedata", result);
            attr.addFlashAttribute("invoicedata", invoicedata);
            model.addAttribute("invoicedata", invoicedata);
            model.addAttribute("bindingResult", result);
            return "add";
```

Now when I am sending the form without the `receptionDate`, I get a beautiful line from Logger:

```
ERROR: Reception date is empty!
```

So it IS validated correctly.

But I have tried many many things and I cannot even get close to show the line:

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('receptionDate')}" th:errors="*{receptionDate}">Error.</span>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have seen solutions for this on few different pages on the Web, the construct: `${#fields.hasErrors()}` is used everywhere, everyone is using the `addFlashAttribute`, and it is not working in my case.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is `return "add";` from the `if` block. everything else is already part of the model. So basically remove the adding of things to the `Model` and flash attributes.

Comment: @M.Deinum - all I got is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'invoicedata' available as request attribute

Comment: Are you doing `return "add";` or `return "redirect:add"? As that would make a huge difference. Also try `@ModelAttribute("invoicedata")` instead of just `@ModelAttribute`. If you compile without method argument names the binding wont automatically discover the attribute name.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did how You suggested, and now the validator has stopped validating my inputs...

Comment: You should leave the `@Validated`, I didn't suggest to remove that.

Comment: @M.Deinum but I havent removed `@Validated`, I don't know what sort of strange things are happening now...

Comment: Did you bind the validator to the databinder? Can you add the full controller?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, like this:     `@InitBinder("invoiceData")
    protected void initPersonFormBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(invoiceFormValidator);
    }`

Comment: `invoiceData` != `invoicedata` ... The name of your model is wrong in the initbinder or in your form. The names must match.

Comment: The name for the model attribute you use in the GET method to fill the method, use in the `@InitBinder` and in the POST methods `@ModelAttribute` must all be the same. Else things will start to diverge and not match, and validation and error reporting stops to work.